# Errors while parsing Salesforce Partner WSDL using wsimport

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, salesforce, wsimport

I want  to connect to Salesforce using Java. However, when I try to parse partner.wsdl using `wsimport` I get the following errors:

```
parsing WSDL...
[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns:ID' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 29 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl#types?schema1
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeGlobalTheme" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 1830 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "DescribeGlobalTheme" is generated from here.
  line 759 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeApprovalLayout" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 2005 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "DescribeApprovalLayout" is generated from here.
  line 1094 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "com.sforce.soap.partner.DescribeLayout" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 1954 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "DescribeLayout" is generated from here.
  line 1112 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 1830 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 759 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 2005 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 1094 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 1954 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 1112 of file:/C:/Users/Rajasekhar/Desktop/partner.wsdl
```

This WSDL was generated from Salesforce itself. How am I supposed to generate the classes needed to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The problems are caused by the WSDL using duplicate names that differ only in casing:

```xml
<complexType name="DescribeGlobalTheme">
```

```xml
<element name="describeGlobalTheme">
```

This is most easily solved by running with an appropriate JAXB extension:

```sh
wsimport -extension -B-XautoNameResolution ...
```

This will then correctly generate two separate classes:

```java
@XmlType(name = "DescribeGlobalTheme", propOrder = { "global", "theme" })
public class DescribeGlobalTheme {
```

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "describeGlobalTheme")
public class DescribeGlobalTheme2 {
```

Alternatively, use the [Force.com Web Services Connector](https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc) instead.